# Java Spring Link Associate One to One relation

Tags: java, spring, rest

hoping I can get some assistance resolving a particular issue. I am basically trying to create a rest api endpoint that displays my one to one relationship between my User & UserProfile class. I am trying to do this using annotations but I'm not having any luck. I can't seem to return both the user info as well as associated profile info. Here are my classes

```
package com.account.service.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String email;

    private Boolean active;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date created_at;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date updated_at;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private UserProfile userProfile;

    public User(){}

    public User(String email, Boolean active, String password, Date created_at, Date updated_at) {
        this.email = email;
        this.active = active;
        this.password = password;
        this.created_at = created_at;
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Date getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public void setCreated_at(Date created_at) {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }

    public Date getUpdated_at() {
        return updated_at;
    }

    public void setUpdated_at(Date updated_at) {
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
    }

    public UserProfile getUserProfile() {
        return userProfile;
    }

    public void setUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile) {
        this.userProfile = userProfile;
    }
}
```

and here is the User Profile

```
package com.account.service.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_profiles")
public class UserProfile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String first_name;

    private String last_name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private User user;

    public UserProfile(){}

    public UserProfile(String first_name, String last_name, User user) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

The response I get is the following which is missing the profile association.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "ul@gmail.com",
        "active": true,
        "created_at": "2017-12-21",
        "updated_at": "2017-12-21"
    }
]
```

Any thoughts on what the issue could be?

The intention is to display the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "ul@gmail.com",
        "active": true,
        "created_at": "2017-12-21",
        "updated_at": "2017-12-21",
        "profile": {
            "id": 1,
            "first_name": "master",
            "last_name": "splinter"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: In User class you use `@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")` Where are you defining this column on UserProfile class ?

Comment: The user profiles table has a corresponding user_id that is a fk on the users table. I don’t have this listed within the profiles class though.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the FETCH EAGER parameter?

Comment: Tried that also doesn't look like that works for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, if anyone else is stuck on an issue like this please take a look at `@JsonBackReference` this should be used on your User class not on your Profile class.